# HP UX iostat on File System

Tags: filesystems, hp-ux, iostat, sar

I have a server running HP UX 11 OS and I'm trying to have I/O statistics for File System and not disk.

For example, I have 50 disk attached to the server when I type iostat (here under output of iostat for 3 disks) :

```
disk9     508   31.4    1.0
disk10     53    1.5    1.0
disk11      0    0.0    1.0
```

And I have File Systems (df output) :

```
/c101            (/dev/VGAPPLI/c101_lv): 66426400 blocks       1045252 i-nodes
/c102            (/dev/VGAPPLI/c102_lv): 360190864 blocks       5672045 i-nodes
/c103            (/dev/VGAPPLI/c103_lv): 150639024 blocks       2367835 i-nodes
/c104            (/dev/VGAPPLI/c104d_lv): 75852825 blocks       11944597 i-nodes
```

Is it possible on hp-ux to have I/O statistics for filesystems and not disks?

Answer (score 1):

Glance can do metrics per file system.

Given this Advisor syntax file:

```
headersprinted=headersprinted
if headersprinted != 1 then {
print "DATE       TIME     FILESYSTEM                   FIR     LIR     LRBR     LRR     LWBR      LWR     PIR     PRBR     PRR     PWBR     PWR"
headersprinted = 1
}
filesystem loop
{
print GBL_STATDATE|12," ",
GBL_STATTIME|9," ",
FS_DIRNAME|24,
FS_FILE_IO_RATE|8,
FS_LOGL_IO_RATE|8,
FS_LOGL_READ_BYTE_RATE|9,
FS_LOGL_READ_RATE|8,
FS_LOGL_WRITE_BYTE_RATE|9,
FS_LOGL_WRITE_RATE|8,
FS_PHYS_IO_RATE|8,
FS_PHYS_READ_BYTE_RATE|9,
FS_PHYS_READ_RATE|8,
FS_PHYS_WRITE_BYTE_RATE|9,
FS_PHYS_WRITE_RATE|8
}
```

Glance can be started in advisor only mode and output directed to file.

```
nohup glance -aos ./filesystem_advisor.conf -j 60 > glance_output_filesystem_$$.txt 2>/dev/null &
```

For more on the metrics, see the documentation or [the Oracle blog where I found this example.](http://www.ora-solutions.net/web/2008/08/25/filesystem-io-monitoring-with-hp-ux-glance/)